# Obj-C - Building custom app messenger, increase speed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've built a custom messenger inside of my iOS (obj-c) mobile app, and the messenger takes FOREVER to send data to the database. How I have it set up now: the moment my user taps the 'send' button, the application starts posting the necessary data (the message they entered into a uitextfield, sending user id, first name, last name...) to the backend database (it's posting content to a Drupal CMS). That said, completing this action takes a solid 10-15 seconds which is WAY too long.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can speed up this process? Take a look at the code below:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {

    _sendButton.enabled = NO;

    NSString *sentText = self.replyField.text;

    if ([self.messageData count] > 0) {

         [self.sendButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:178/255.0 green:178/255.0 blue:178/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.activityIndicatorSend.hidden = NO;
        [self.activityIndicatorSend startAnimating];


    NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [nodeData setObject:@"messages" forKey:@"type"];


    NSDictionary *messageValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sentText, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *finalMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:messageValues] forKey:@"und"];

    [nodeData setObject:finalMessage forKey:@"body"];

        self.replyField.text = @"";

        NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageData objectForKey:@"uid"];


        NSDictionary *targetMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetedUser, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
        NSDictionary *finalUser = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetMessage] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:finalUser forKey:@"field_targetuser"];


        NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];

        DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
        [session setUser:userDictInfo];

        [session user];


    [nodeData setValue: @"Re:" forKey:@"title"];

    [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            NSLog(@"Message sent successfully!");

            self.sendButton.hidden = NO;
            self.activityIndicatorSend.hidden = YES;

          [self updateMessages];


        });

        self.replyField.text = @"";


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];



    }
```

Comment: So, it’s taking 10-15 seconds for you to see the “message sent” log statement? Or for it appear on the web or another device. Can you please clarify precisely what you’re benchmarking?

Comment: FWIW, if you’re looking for real-time chatting, sending HTTP requests is likely not the right approach. You’d often adopt some socket-based architecture. https://www.raywenderlich.com/537-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: @Rob For me to see the 'message sent' log statement.

Comment: OK, you’ll want to narrow it down. For example, I’d put a `NSLog` right before `nodeSave`, and make sure there isn’t something unrelated cause the delay. I’d also use [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) to observe and benchmark the actual network request. (e.g.make sure the request isn’t unusual long, see precisely how long it took before the server responded, make sure there isn’t some auth silliness going on, etc.) Bottom line, diagnose how much of the problem rests in the server vs the client.